# div element with scroll at end

Tags: html, scroll

I have a div element that at the beginning is hidden. It appears when a button is clicked. the problem is that this div has a scroll and when it appears, it is at the end of scroll. How can I fix this?

The code is something like this:

```
<div style="width: 412px; height: 351px; overflow: auto; position: relative;"> 
   <div style="width: 540px;">
      Here is a form
   </div>
</div>
```

The first div is that is hidden at the beginning.

Comment: Are you able to show us some code? What's in the div? What is the code that you are using to show the div?

Comment: Edit your original question with the code, and make sure you format it as code so it shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your button that displays the div, add this javascript to set the div to be scrolled to the top.

document.getElementById('id').scrollTop = 0;

---

Per your comment, if you want to set the scroll without modifying the button's code, you could try running it on page load:

```
<body onload="javascript: document.getElementById('id').scrollTop = 0;">
```

Or, you could run it at the bottom of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('id').scrollTop = 0;
</script>
```

Comment: added other options to my answer.  Not sure though - if you can't edit the button, can you edit the html anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest showing your code, providing a link, or creating a test page for people to view and debug. It's difficult to see what's going on without some context.

Here's an example that, I believe, shows what you want: http://jsbin.com/emoji4/edit

This uses the jQuery library, so I'm not sure it will meet your needs.